# Dynamic piping system

Tags: modelica

I try to model a hydraulic system in Twinbuilder with Modelica. But I get always errors which I think has to do with convergence problem. To understand what the problem is, I simplified my system to a dynamic pipe, fixed boundary, and swept volume whose movement will be given by a sinus function. But I still get an error in this simplified case.  I am able to compile the model even though I get warnings. When I try to solve the model,. It is not solved. I want to ask if you give me a suggestion on this problem?

This is block diagramm of the model

[image: l]

Errors which I get when I try to solve the model are as follows:

> Error occured when entering initialization mode on Hochdruckreiniger3_1.

> Error encountered in the Initialize function of user model.

> Error encountered while initializing the simulators

> Residual function evaluation failed at initial point for "1"
> From Hochdruckreiniger3_1:       Jacobian evaluation failed at initial point for "1"
> From Hochdruckreiniger3_1:     Failed to find a consistent solution in event iteration in "1", 0 at        0.0000000000000000E+000
> From Hochdruckreiniger3_1:   Residual function evaluation failed at initial point for "3" "#r171#"
> From Hochdruckreiniger3_1: Initialization failed.

The code is as follows:

```
model Hochdruckreiniger3
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real pi = 3.14;
    Real N = 2800;
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Swept1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = true,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15);
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system;
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = 46.72,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = -pi/2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe1 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);


equation

    //Connection(s)
    connect(Posit1.flange, Swept1.flange);
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(pipe1.port_b, Swept1.ports[1]);
    connect(boundary.ports[1], pipe1.port_a);
end  Hochdruckreiniger3;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dymola shows two errors in you model:

1. `pi` must be a `constant` or `parameter` to comply with the variability of the parameter `phase` in the `sine` block. By the way, it is good practice to refer to `Modelica.Constants.pi`.
2. in `swept1` you set `use_portsData = true` but don´t provide any port data.

Fixing these two issues, the model simulates but warns you about initial values not being explicitly set.

Comment: variability: https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/equations/variables/#variability

Comment: Yes, please never declare pi yourself, especially not to a wrong value, instead use `import pi = Modelica.Constants.pi;` or use the full name `Modelica.Constants.pi` directly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it warns me about initial values (e.g der(Swept1.medium.p), der(pipe1.mediums[1].h),der(pipe1.mediums[2].p)) I don"t understand how to set these initial values explicitly.

Comment: My experience is that missing guess start-values for derivatives are normally that problematic; compared to missing guess start-values for other variables.