# Hydraulic system(Valve, Sweeping Volume, Pipe)- Modelica

Tags: modelica

This is a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605426/dynamic-pipingsystem-modelica/64605635#64605635). I am able to solve the simplified case. Now I make it more complicated. I insert valves( High pressure and low-pressure valve). The opening of these valves is dependent on the movement of sweeping volume. if sweeping volume increases, the low-pressure valve opens, if it decreases, high-pressure valve opens.

In this image, it is seen the left system and it works. But when I add another part (high-pressure valve and high-pressure boundary condition) it gives an error when I try to solve.

[image]

In this second image, you can see the whole system.
[image]

These are the errors that I get when I try to solve

> Error occurred when entering initialization mode on Hochdruckreiniger3_1

> Error encountered in the Initialize function of the user model.

> Error encountered while initializing the simulators

This is the code.

```
model Hochdruckreiniger2
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real N = 2800;
    Real f;
    Real opening_NP;
    Real opening_HP;
    import Modelica.Constants.pi;
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Swept1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        portsData = {Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter = 0.012), Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=
        0.012)},
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 2,
        use_portsData = true,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15);
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system;
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible Hochdruckventile (
        dp_nominal = 96.38,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        rho_nominal = 1019.921,
        opening = opening_HP,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible Niederdruckventile (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        rho_nominal = 998.388,
        opening = opening_NP,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = 46.72,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = -pi/2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1 (p = 10e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe1 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe2 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe3 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);


equation
    //T_per=pi/(180*3600*N/60);//Radian  
        f=(((V_max-V_tod)/2)*sin(2*pi*time*(60/N)))+V_tod+(V_max-V_tod)/2;
          if der(f)>=0 then
            opening_NP=1;
            opening_HP=0;
           else
            opening_NP=0;
            opening_HP=1;
          end if;
    //Connection(s)
    connect(Posit1.flange, Swept1.flange);
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(boundary.ports[1], pipe.port_a);
    connect(pipe.port_b, Niederdruckventile.port_a);
    connect(Niederdruckventile.port_b, pipe1.port_a);
    connect(pipe1.port_b, Swept1.ports[1]);
    connect(Swept1.ports[2], pipe2.port_a);
    connect(pipe2.port_b, Hochdruckventile.port_a);
    connect(Hochdruckventile.port_b, pipe3.port_a);
    connect(pipe3.port_b, boundary1.ports[1]);
end  Hochdruckreiniger2;
```

If you can help me it would be great. Thanks in advance!